# Space-track SGP4 on MATLAB

Tags: orbital-mechanics, astrodynamics

I am new to orbital calculations and online resources, so I was hoping someone would be willing to help me get started. I have downloaded the space-track Astrodynamic standard library and I am attempting to use their example code for the SGP4 propagator, however I can't even seem to get the input and output files correct... I made a text file with the TLE and 6P-Card data, but it won't recognize it. Would someone be able to step me through the process of using the example code from space-track for the SGP4 propagator? It should really just be entering the input TLE and a name for the outputs, but for some reason it won't work for me.

Comment: This question is almost certainly not a good fit for SE. If it gets closed, feel free to contact me (info in profile) for free help

Answer (score 1):

Getting the 6P card right is tricky.  You should read [How is an input card for SGP4/other astro standards packages crafted?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/58212/how-is-an-input-card-for-sgp4-other-astro-standards-packages-crafted) for detailed instructions.  The other main thing to check is whether the TLEs you're trying to use have been cut and pasted through something that modifies the empty spaces between words, as HTML does outside of $<\texttt{pre}>$ tags.  If all the gaps between fields are single spaces, then there are some crucial space characters missing, since TLE is a ***fixed-length*** record format.  For example, in the TLE posted in the 6P card answer, five gaps are two spaces long, and one gap is three spaces.  If some of those space characters get dropped, the result is an invalid TLE that the parser will correctly tell you has been corrupted.